# Blocks in Objective-C and Multithreds

Tags: asynchronous, objective-c-blocks, grand-central-dispatch

Intro:
On my Xcode project i’ve 3 datastore :SFGroupsItemStore, SFFeedsItemStore, SFQuestsItemStore. All of this class are subclass of 1 my custom class and all are singleton.
Each of this class i use at next controllers : SFGroupsListViewController SFFeedsListViewController, SFQuestsListViewController. All of this class has method: -downloadItems

Problem:
I want to create one controller SFHomeViewController, that will present table with all 3 datastore mixed.
For resolve this problem i want to create aggregator SFHomeItemStore, also singleton, and i want that this class has method -downloadItems.

So, i’v done it, there are the implemaemtation of -downloadIItems in SF HomeItemStore

1 step:

```
- (NSArray *)downloadItemsFrom:(int32_t)from withLimit:(int)limit andDirection:(NSString *)direction{

     NSArray     *groupsItems     =     [[SFGroupsItemStore shared] downloadItems];
     NSArray     *feedsItems     =     [[SFFeedsItemStore shared] downloadItems];
     NSArray     *questsItems     =     [[SFQuestsItemStore shared] downloadItems];

     NSMutableArray     *mixedArray     =     [NSMutableArray array];

     [mixedArray addObjectsFromArray:groupsItems];
     [mixedArray addObjectsFromArray:feedsItems];
     [mixedArray addObjectsFromArray:questsItems];

     NSArray     *sortedArray     =     [mixedArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"createdAt" ascending:NO]]];
     return sortedArray;

}
```

That work’s fine for me.

2 step:
But i do not like that call of method -downloadItems goes sequentaly, that why for call this method i need to spend more time
But if i add GCD i’ve a problem,
Now implementation method -downloadItems is

```
- (NSArray *)downloadItemsFrom:(int32_t)from withLimit:(int)limit andDirection:(NSString *)direction{

     __block     NSArray     *sortedArray     =     nil;

     __block     NSArray     *groupsItems;
     __block     NSArray     *feedsItems;
     __block     NSArray     *questsItems;

     dispatch_group_t     groupedTask     =     dispatch_group_create();
     dispatch_queue_t     globalQueue     =     dispatch_get_global_queue( 0, 0 );

     dispatch_group_async( groupedTask, globalQueue, ^{
          groupsItems     =     [[SFGroupsItemStore shared] downloadItems];
     } );

     dispatch_group_async( groupedTask, globalQueue, ^{
          feedsItems     =     [[SFFeedsItemStore shared] downloadItems];
     } );

     dispatch_group_async( groupedTask, globalQueue, ^{
          questsItems     =     [[SFQuestsItemStore shared] downloadItems];
     } );

     dispatch_group_notify( groupedTask, globalQueue, ^{

          NSMutableArray     *mixedArray     =     [NSMutableArray array];
          [mixedArray addObjectsFromArray:groupsItems];
          [mixedArray addObjectsFromArray:feedsItems];
          [mixedArray addObjectsFromArray:questsItems];

          sortedArray     =     [mixedArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"createdAt" ascending:NO]]];

     } );

     return sortedArray;

}
```

Problem is that method return result regardless of dispatch_group_notify and that why array sortedArray is empty

So, my question is:
**How i can do that method will return result only after end of dispatch_group_notify function?**

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. If it's ok for your method to block the current thread, then you can use  [`dispatch_group_wait`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/#//apple_ref/c/func/dispatch_group_wait).
2. Use a completion handler to return your `NSArray`.

### dispatch_group_wait

From the docs:

> Waits synchronously for the previously submitted block objects to
>   complete; returns if the blocks do not complete before the specified
>   timeout period has elapsed.

Your method would look something like this:

```
- (NSArray *)downloadItemsFrom:(int32_t)from withLimit:(int)limit andDirection:(NSString *)direction{

    // ... 

    dispatch_group_async( groupedTask, globalQueue, ^{
         groupsItems     =     [[SFGroupsItemStore shared] downloadItems];
    } );

    // ...

    dispatch_group_wait(groupedTask, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);

    NSMutableArray     *mixedArray     =     [NSMutableArray array];
    [mixedArray addObjectsFromArray:groupsItems];
    [mixedArray addObjectsFromArray:feedsItems];
    [mixedArray addObjectsFromArray:questsItems];

    sortedArray     =     [mixedArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"createdAt" ascending:NO]]];

    return sortedArray;
}
```

### Using a completion handler

*This is the method I prefer.*

You'd need to change your method signature so that it takes a completion handler as a new parameter, and returns `void` instead of `NSArray`. With this method, you'd still be using `dispatch_group_notify`.

It would look something like this:

```
- (void)downloadItemsFrom:(int32_t)from 
                withLimit:(int)limit 
                direction:(NSString *)direction 
     andCompletionHandler:(void (^)(NSArray*))completionHandler
{

    // ... 

    dispatch_group_async( groupedTask, globalQueue, ^{
         groupsItems     =     [[SFGroupsItemStore shared] downloadItems];
    } );

    // ...

     dispatch_group_notify( groupedTask, globalQueue, ^{

          NSMutableArray     *mixedArray     =     [NSMutableArray array];
          [mixedArray addObjectsFromArray:groupsItems];
          [mixedArray addObjectsFromArray:feedsItems];
          [mixedArray addObjectsFromArray:questsItems];

          sortedArray     =     [mixedArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"createdAt" ascending:NO]]];

          completionHandler(sortedArray);
     } );
}
```

Calling it would now look like:

```
[object downloadItemsFrom:... 
                withLimit:... 
                 diretion:... 
     andCompletionHandler:^(NSArray *items) 
{

}];
```